# Java: Search a word in multiple files

Tags: java, search, arraylist, indexof

Basically, i need to check for a word's occurances within multiple files.
Also, a word might exist in a single text file multiple times.
I want to save positions of a word for each file; so i wrote the code below:

```
    public static void findWord(String word, File file){
        try{
             BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(file)));
            String line;
            ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.indexOf(word)>-1){
                    list.add(line.indexOf(word));
                }
            }
           System.out.println(file +": "+ list);

            input.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My code fails to add to list after first successful occurance. So I have only one element within every array.
How do i fix it? 

P.S My text files consists of one line

Comment: Do you realize that even your code actually stores word positions within lines and not the whole file? Also the line "line.lastIndexOf(word);" has no effect.

Comment: My bad, I forget to mention that my text files consist of one line, i've converted CVS into txt.

Comment: @user1115605 : Aren't you suppose to add line.lastIndexOf(word); to the list too, to save the last occurrence of word in the list? Regards

Comment: Yes, line.lastIndexOf(word) has no effect, i was trying something like to continue moving in string until the end of the file. I have no idea how to do it, so i was just improvising

Comment: You need another loop for that - see the answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes the fix (replace your while loop with this):

`while ((line = input.readLine ()) != null)
{
    int index = -1;
    while ((index = line.indexOf (word, index + 1) > -1)
    {
        list.add (index);
    }
}`